# Constructor Method overload Java

Tags: java, constructor, overloading

Very simple Rational class I'm trying to create.

If, in the main methods, one calls `Rational(2)` then `num = 2` and `den = 1`

If one calls `Rational(2, 4)` then `num = 2` and `den = 4`

Here is my code:

```
public class Rational {

    public long num;    
    public long den;

    Rational(long arg1, long arg2){

        num = arg1;    
        den = arg2;

    }

    Rational(long arg1){

        long x = 1;
        Rational(arg1, x);  //Rational(long, long) is undefined for type Rational

    }

}
```

I have commented the error message I have no idea how to fix.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use the `this` keyword but it needs to be the first statement in the constructor so it wont be possible to define `x` before that

```
this(arg1, 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
this(arg1, 1);
```

You call the other constructor using the `this` keyword, similar to how you would use `super`. It must also be the first statement in the constructor body. Since it is first, you will have to change the way you pass in `x` in your example.